# mongoose populate as an instance object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When using mongoose's populate, you can get the document back but it is not an object instance where your schema methods are defined.

```
var tweetSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  owner: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  message: { type: String },
});

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true },
});

userSchema.methods.test = function(){
  return 'test'
}

Tweet.findOne({}).populate('user').exec(function(err,tweet){
  console.log(tweet.user.test);
});
```

This will result in an error 'Cannot read property 'userTwit' of undefined' as tweet.user is just a hash and not a document instance. Is there a way to make population return the document instance???

What would be a nice way to make something like this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you use `lean()`, the populated fields *are* doc instances.

Looks like your User field in `tweetSchema` is called `owner`, not `user`, so this should work:

```
Tweet.findOne({}).populate('owner').exec(function(err, tweet){
  console.log(tweet.owner.test());
});
```